# Replace duplicate columns in data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `data frame` in `pyspark`. This data frame has say some columns with special characters.

```
cols = df.schema.names

cols
['abc test', 'test*abc', 'eng)test', 'abc_&test']

reps = ((' ', '_&'), ('(', '*_'), (')', '_*'), ('{', '#_'), ('}', '_#'), (';', '_##'), ('.', '_$'), (',', '_$$'), ('=', '_**'))

def col_rename(x):
    new_cols = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), reps, x)

for i in cols:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(i, col_rename(cols, i))
return df
```

Now I want to see if after replacing the special characters in the column names if there are any duplicate columns.
As we can see there is a duplicate of columns in the new_cols `abc_&test`

I want to return extra `_`  `underscore` when this happens.

My new_cols shoul be like below

```
['abc__&test', 'test*_abc', 'eng_*test', 'abc_&test']
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you would need to *change the column names* as defined in

```
reps = [(' ', '_&'), ('(', '*_'), (')', '_*'), ('{', '#_'), ('}', '_#'), (';', '_##'), ('.', '_$'), (',', '_$$'), ('=', '_**')]
```

which can be done by *creating a new list*

```
replacedCols = []
for col in cols:
    for x in reps:
        col = col.replace(x[0], x[1])
    replacedCols.append(col)
```

> > Now I want to see if after replacing the special characters in the column names if there are any duplicate columns. I want to return extra _ underscore when this happens.

You can do that by *checking for each column names in the `replacedCols` array*

```
checkCols = replacedCols[:]
for index, col in enumerate(replacedCols):
    checkCols[index] = ''
    replacedCols[index]
    if col in checkCols:
        replacedCols[index] = col.replace('_', '__')
```

Thus you are done. Final step is to *rename* the columns

```
for index, col in enumerate(cols):
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, replacedCols[index])

df.show(truncate=False)
```

You should have

```
+----------+--------+---------+---------+
|abc__&test|test*abc|eng_*test|abc_&test|
+----------+--------+---------+---------+
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be modified to check for new_cols is already in present in columns and if so, substitute with extra underscore,

```
import re

reps = (' ', '_&'), ('(', '*_'), (')', '_*'), ('{', '#_'), ('}', '_#'), (';', '_##'), ('.', '_$'), (',', '_$$'), ('=', '_**')

def col_rename(x):
    new_cols = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), reps, x)
    if new_cols != x:
       new_cols = re.sub('_','__',new_cols) if new_cols in cols else new_cols
    return new_cols

for i in cols:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(i, col_rename(i))

>>> df.show(0)
+----------+--------+---------+---------+
|abc__&test|test*abc|eng_*test|abc_&test|
+----------+--------+---------+---------+
+----------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I am getting `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in col_rename
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'` error

Comment: Typo, my bad, have edited the answer now. Instead of col_rename(cols), it's col_rename(i).