# replaced list back to original list in python

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a `list` like below in `python/pyspark` like below. I want to convert the special characters in the list to something else.

I have done like below.

```
cols = ['abc test', 'test*abc', 'eng)test', 'abc_&test']

reps = [(' ', '_&'), ('(', '*_'), (')', '_*'), ('{', '#_'), ('}', '_#'), (';', '_##'), ('.', '_$'), (',', '_$$'), ('=', '_**')]

replacedCols = []
for col in cols:
    for x in reps:
        col = col.replace(x[0], x[1])
    replacedCols.append(col)

checkCols = replacedCols[:]
for index, col in enumerate(replacedCols):
    checkCols[index] = ''
    replacedCols[index]
    if col in checkCols:
        replacedCols[index] = col.replace('_', '__')
```

The new list is like below:

```
New_cols = ['abc__&test', 'test*abc', 'eng_*test', 'abc_&test']
```

Now I want to convert this list back to the original list:

```
new_cols = ['abc__&test', 'test*abc', 'eng_*test', 'abc_&test']

reps = (('_&', ' '), ('*_', '('), ('_*', ')'), ('#_', '{'), ('_#', '}'), ('_##', ';'), ('_$', '.'), ('_$$', ','), ('_**', '='))


replaced_ColsCols = []
for col in new_cols:
    for x in reps:
        col = col.replace(x[0], x[1])
    replaced_Cols.append(col)

check_Cols = replaced_Cols[:]
for index, col in enumerate(replaced_Cols):
    check_Cols[index] = ''
    replaced_Cols[index]
    if col in check_Cols:
        replaced_Cols[index] = col.replace('__', '_')

print(replaced_Cols)
```

I got the result like below which is not the same as the original list

```
old_cols = ['abc_ test', 'test*abc', 'eng)test', 'abc test']
```

What do I need to do to get the the desired result

Comment: Where is `old_cols` in your code?

Comment: @johnashu I want to check If I can go back to create the original list from the converted list

Comment: Why do you need to convert them back?. the cols variable remains unchanged.. just call it

Comment: @johnashu I know I have the cols variable and can call it but I want to check if I can revert back the changes to original list

Comment: But you have not made any changes to the original list.. you have gone to a lot of effort to create new lists..

Comment: @johnashu ok Consider this scenario I have converted the list and saved the list as a file, and closed the python shell. Now when i open a new python shell and read this file I will have a list. Now I want to convert the list back to the original list I had in the previous `python session`

Comment: ok..I just wanted to be clear on what you were trying to achieve! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that it is the continued post from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120835/replace-duplicate-columns-in-data-frame) and you are trying to reverse the idea presented as answer in there .

In that post you had changed `['abc test', 'test*abc', 'eng)test', 'abc_&test']` to `['abc__&test', 'test*abc', 'eng_*test', 'abc_&test']` and you want to reverse the changes.

**You don't have to reverse the changes as you already have the original list**

But **in case you want to learn new stuffs** here's the working code for you

```
new_cols = ['abc__&test', 'test*abc', 'eng_*test', 'abc_&test']
reps = (('_&', ' '), ('*_', '('), ('_*', ')'), ('#_', '{'), ('_#', '}'), ('_##', ';'), ('_$', '.'), ('_$$', ','), ('_**', '='))

for index, col in enumerate(new_cols):
    if '__' in col:
        new_cols[index] = col.replace('__', "_")

replaced_ColsCols = []
checkCols = new_cols[:]
for col in new_cols:
    if new_cols.count(col) > 1:
        checkCols.remove(col)
    if col in checkCols:
        for x in reps:
            col = col.replace(x[0], x[1])
    replaced_ColsCols.append(col)

print replaced_ColsCols
```

which should give you

```
['abc test', 'test*abc', 'eng)test', 'abc_&test']
```